# The user authentication in tomcat is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am new to java/tomcat and was trying to basically add a user to the manager-GUI role. But even though I edited on the file conf/tomcat-users.xml and added as it is supposed to be(defining the roles and everything), the server doesn't accept the user. I restarted my server for 10 times and also edited the file that many times, and it still didn't work. I used Atom as XML editor and Eclipse jee oxygen to run the server. What would be the problem here?

Comment: Can you please post your `tomcat-users.xml`?

Comment: also examining the  `[tomcat-root]/logs/catalina.out` may be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Most likely mistake: not un-commenting out the default contents of `tomcat-users.xml`.

The file that ships with Tomcat has all of the contents commented-out so that the server has no default usernames and passwords enabled. You have to change change the username and password *plus* remove the `<--` and `-->` delimiters around the users.

```xml
*<!--*
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="role1"/>
*-->*
```

I've added asterisks around the comments you need to remove (I'm not sure how to force-format code in markdown). Remember to remove all `<role>` and `<user>` definitions that you do not want to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic Tomcat config that works in Netbeans, should be the same for Eclipse :

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
          version="1.0">
<user username="root" password="root" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script" />
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
```

It is my understanding that you NEED to ADD a manager-script role for an IDE to be able to manage the server.

Comment: How should be called this configuration file? Where should we put it?